# Android webview how to include fonts awesome icon

Tags: android, css, webview

I have populate a webview having css file with font icons like this

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0')
```

but the webview in android is not displaying the icon of fontAwesome

this is how i load webview

```
  web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
            "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/css/font-awesome.min.css\" />"
                        +"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/css/bootstrap.min.css\" />"+
                    "<script src=\"file:///android_asset/css/jquery.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>"+
                    "<script src=\"file:///android_asset/css/bootstrap.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>"+
                    "</head><body>" + text + "</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Do you have the font file (otf)in assets?

Comment: try cdn instead of downloading it https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: yes i have fonts in assets folder(otf,ttf,oet...)

Comment: not working from online link cdn

Comment: Did you solve this?